# How to group datagridview Rows same id

Tags: sql, vb.net

Hello i have problem to display invoice details product id and quantity and selling price but its display duplicated product id and name
i use this code

```
Private Sub InvoiceDetailsFrm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Invoiceshowsales()
End Sub
```

[image]

```
   Sub Invoiceshowsales()
    
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        Dim sdate As String = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        Con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select SalesDetails.ProductId,Products.Prodname,SalesDetails.Quantity,SalesDetails.Sellingprice,SalesDetails.UnitId,SalesDetails.Sellingpricetotal From SalesDetails,products where InvoiceId='" & TxtInvoiceId.Text & "'", Con)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
    
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr.Item("ProductId").ToString, dr.Item("Prodname").ToString, dr.Item("Quantity").ToString, dr.Item("Sellingprice").ToString, dr.Item("UnitId").ToString, dr.Item("Sellingpricetotal").ToString)
        End While
        dr.Close()
        Con.Close()
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Side note, use parameters to prevent SQLi attacks and format issues. Also you could fill a `DataTable` and then set that as the `DataSource` to `DataGridView1.DataSource` property, you don't have to loop over the reader. Finally, if you have duplicates, you could use a `Distinct` as part of your query.

Comment: @Trevor where can i put distinct please